# Remote images and sizes for hdpi/mdpi/ldpi etc

Tags: android, android-image

So on device there's the drawable directories for hdpi, mdpi, ldpi etc...

Now lets say I want to download images from the internet to view in the app (on the fly).

Can I have the three different densities of image available for download? Is there some way I can check if the current device is hdpi/mdpi/ldpi and download the right resolution accordingly? Or is it much more simple than that?

I guess if I download a high res image onto a hdpi phone then it will assume its a mdpi image that just has larger dimensions than intended?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you get the density programatically

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics(); 
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics); 
switch(metrics.densityDpi){ 
     case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW: 
                break; 
     case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM: 
                 break; 
     case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH: 
                 break; 
}
```